# Visual Studio 2010 C++ - failed to load and parse the manifest

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I create a new C++ project and press F5 and I'm always getting the same errors

```
Warning 1   warning MSB5018: Failed to delete the temporary file "C:\Users\VALUAR3\AppData\Local\Temp\42286e60372d4705a5dd7310357dd43b.rsp". The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\VALUAR3\AppData\Local\Temp\42286e60372d4705a5dd7310357dd43b.rsp' because it is being used by another process. C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets 268 6   IBoss
```

And

```
Error   2   error c1010070: Failed to load and parse the manifest. The system cannot find the file specified.   c:\Users\VALUAR3\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\IBoss\IBoss\Debug\IBoss.exe.intermediate.manifest    IBoss
```

I've even reinstalled windows a couple of times and tried other versions like VS 2008 , 2012, but no succes, same error every time.

My code

```
 // IBoss.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem? This is very frustrating..

Answer (score 0):

did you try not to generate the manifest?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2c0w594.aspx

Comment: Now i'm getting unable to start program C:\.....debug\iboss.exe. System can't find the file specified

Comment: ok so did you try the default console application, just as Microsoft prooses it and tried to compile/run it? (file/newp roject/Visual C++/Console Application) ?

Comment: Yep... Not even one chance

Comment: so try it before to be sure that VS is installed correctly

Comment: It is, i've even reinstaled windows